# Policy based access control libraries - alternatives to ory/ladon

Tags: authorization, access-control

I would like to add policy based access control to my application, similar in concept to AWS IAM. I am trying to assess what's out there that I can leverage for this. I have come across this project:

https://github.com/ory/ladon

This seems promising, any other alternative projects that others are familiar with?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the following:

- XACML ([AuthzForce](https://github.com/authzforce), [Axiomatics](https://www.axiomatics.com/))
- [Open Policy Agent](https://www.axiomatics.com/)
- [ALFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALFA_(XACML))